# How to pass parameters to sql script via psql \i command

Tags: postgresql, psql, sql-injection

The psql `\i` command is able to execute a given SQL script but I need a way to pass parameters to the script.

Example: say you have this simple script

```sql
select * from :table LIMIT 1;
```

I've tried

```
my_db=> \i my-script.sql -v table="core.product"
```

but got this error

```
psql:my-script.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: select * from :table LIMIT 1;
                      ^
\i: extra argument "-v" ignored
\i: extra argument "table="core.product"" ignored
```

---

I know that running this on terminal will work, but I'm already inside psql.

```
psql -v table="core.product" -f my-script.sql
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\set` to set a variable inside psql.
Read about SQL interpolation in the manual here:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION

Ideally, your script would read:

```
SELECT * FROM :"my_schema".:"my_table" LIMIT 1;
```

With schema and table double-quoted separately, for identifier-interpolation.
Then set schema and table in psql without quotes like:

```
my_db=>\set my_schema core
my_db=>\set my_table product
```

Just the bare, case-sensitive names.
Finally, execute:

```
my_db=>\i my-script.sql
```

This way, the script is safe against SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Would be nice if I was able to run multiple `\set` commands at once

Comment: @MichaelPacheco: You can have multiple `\set` commands in the same line. Like: `\set a b \set c d \set e f`