# Set custom constant in Postgres script

Tags: postgresql, parameter, postgresql-15

In Postgres 15, how can we define constants that pertain to business logic rather than db configuration settings? I'd like to define them within SQL scripts rather than passed through the `psql -v MY_CONSTANT=123` command & I don't care if they persist only for the session.

In prior versions I quietly got away with the following syntax:

```sql
SET MY_CONSTANT TO 123;     -- declared
CALL my_func(:MY_CONSTANT); -- used
```

Which from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-set.html) seems to be intended for modifying known db config settings & explains why I am encountering issues like this:

```
my_script.sql:2: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "my_constant"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three distinct contexts that might pertain to your question:

- Plain SQL in a Postgres session
- PL/pgSQL inside a code block of a function, procedure or `DO` command
- The default interactive terminal psql

The answer for each scope is different. Seems like you are mixing at least two of those.

> `SET MY_CONSTANT TO 123;`     -- declared

`SET` is an SQL command. You can use it to set "customized options". Must contain a dot - as opposed to Postgres settings (GUCs). [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html):

> Custom options have two-part names: an extension name, then a dot, then the parameter name proper, much like qualified names in SQL. An example is `plpgsql.variable_conflict`.

And you retrieve it with `SHOW` or `current_setting()`:

```
SELECT current_setting('custom.my_constant');
```

Only operates on type `text` though. You may need to cast.

> `CALL my_func(:MY_CONSTANT);` -- used

That's the syntax of SQL interpolation in psql, which works for psql variables. See:

- [How to pass parameters to sql script via psql \i command](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300276/how-to-pass-parameters-to-sql-script-via-psql-i-command/300281#300281)
- [How can I quote a named argument passed in to psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188925/939860)

Related:

- [Difference between set, \set and \pset in psql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29593908/939860)
- [Set a temporary global variable during a Postgres query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676236/939860)
- [Declaring variable for a whole script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213919/declaring-variable-for-a-whole-script/213921#213921)

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter I think your answer is complete but I must not be seeing something obvious..

In my postgis scenario I am trying to set the spatial-reference identifier as a constant integer for all `Geometry(Point, :SRID)` columns in my schema.  Defining as `\set SRID 3347` for psql interpolation should have worked, but gives syntax errors when the constant is referenced with & without quotes as `:"SRID"`. Any ideas?

Comment: @eliangius: The interpolation should work while you stay in the same psql session. (Without quotes for an integer literal.) But `Geometry(Point, :SRID)` does not look like a valid PostGis function call.

Comment: SQL interpolation does not work *inside* strings (incl. dollar-quoted strings). You are aware of that? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37716568/939860

Comment: Calling the constant without quotes to get its value is the correct syntax. Turns out the problem was in same line comments I had when defining the constant like `\set MY_CONSTANT 123 ; -- some comment`  does **NOT** work as intended because the whole line is treated as its value(s). 

Comment: @eliangius: Turns out to be related to the original problem: confusing different scopes. Terminating a command with semicolon and the appended comment work in SQL (or PL/pgSQL), but not for psql meta-commands.

Comment: Fair enough. If there's a PL/pgSQL clean way to reference a custom constant without having to do `current_setting('custom.MY_CONSTANT')::INTEGER` love to know of it as that complexity didn't seem to work for type modifiers like postgis' `Geometry()` wanting simple constants.

Comment: You can declare any number of variables in a PL/pgSQL code block. Local to the same code block of course. You could fetch the value in the `DECLARE` section from a "customized option" into such a variable once ... Ask a new question if you need more. Comments are not the place ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "sql only" way then you can use prepared statements in SQL. Such;

```
PREPARE any_name (integer) AS SELECT my_func($1);
EXECUTE any_name (1); -- any constant
```

References:

- [PREPARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html)
- [EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
postgres=# \set my_constant 123
postgres=# SELECT my_func(:my_constant);
 my_func
---------
     123
```

Please note, this syntax only works if you run your scripts in `psql`. If you don't, try this workaround:

```
postgres=# CREATE TEMP TABLE my_vars AS SELECT 123 AS my_constant, 456 AS myother_constant;
SELECT 1

postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_vars;
 my_constant | myother_constant
-------------+------------------
         123 |              456

postgres=# SELECT my_func((SELECT my_constant FROM my_vars));
 my_func
---------
     123
```

The temp table only exists for the current session, it'll be gone after logout.