# How to use a query to set a custom option?

Tags: postgresql

I tried this but it does not work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION answer()
  RETURNS bigint
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
SELECT 42
$$;

SET session.answer = select answer();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`SET` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) only accepts constants. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html#id-1.9.3.174.6)

> constants, identifiers, numbers, or comma-separated lists of these

It does not take parameters, nor can it evaluate subqueries. Parameter substitution only works for basic DML commands (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`).

The function [`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) provides equivalent functionality;

```
SELECT set_config('session.answer', answer()::text, false);
```

Note the cast to `::text`. Postgres parameters only store text.

Related:

- [Set a temporary global variable during a Postgres query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676236/939860)
- [How to reuse a computed value multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72223057/939860)
- [Set custom constant in Postgres script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321386/set-custom-constant-in-postgres-script/321388#321388)